# An olympiad problem

Tags: functions, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I was reading a book about olympiad problems and i encountered this exercise.

Let $f:(0,\infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that $\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} =f(\sqrt{xy})$.

Prove that $\forall x,y,z>0$  $$\frac{f(x)+f(y)+f(z)}{3} =f(\sqrt[3]{xyz})$$

I only managed to prove it for an even number of values but i find difficulties to prove it for odd number of values.

Also we can easily see that a function with this property is $f(x)=lnx$.

Can someone give me a hint??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why is$ f(1)=0$ and $f(x^2)=2f(x)$

Comment: $f(x^2) =f(x^2)+f(x^2)/2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{f(x) + f(y)  + f(z) + f(\sqrt[3]{xyz})}{4} = f(\sqrt[3]{xyz})$ (just apply first formula two times)

Answer (score 0):

Another example function is the constant function

Comment: i know but its trivial..i wanted to find a non trivial example to help me solve it